# axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1 when using SVM

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, multiclass-classification

training data

```py
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Ram Prakash/Downloads/Data.xlsx', 
sheet_name = 'Multiclass')
X = df.drop('Fault Type', axis =1)
y = df.iloc[0:, 10]
y = le.fit_transform(y)

# Train Test split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
test_size=0.3, random_state=2021)
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
X_train, X_test = scaler.transform(X_train), 
scaler.transform(X_test)
```

I am trying to classify the data into multiple classes. However I keep getting this error.

Code:

```py
##Classification by Default parameters
# Fit SVM classifier
clf_default = SVC(kernel='rbf')
clf = OneVsOneClassifier(clf_default).fit(X_train, y_train)
print('(Cross Validation) AUC Score:', np.mean(cross_val_score(estimator=clf, X=X_train, y=y_train, cv=5, scoring = 'roc_auc')))

# Show result
print('(Test set) Confusion Matrix:')
c = label_binarize(y_test, classes = labels)
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, clf.predict(X_test)))
print('(Test set) AUC Score:', roc_auc_score(y_test, clf.predict(X_test), average = 'macro', multi_class = 'ovo'))
```

While running the code I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ram Prakash\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_23060\2986435798.py", line 6, in <cell line: 5>
    print('(Test set) AUC Score:', roc_auc_score(y_test, clf_default.predict(X_test), average = None, multi_class = 'ovo'))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_ranking.py", line 566, in roc_auc_score
    return _multiclass_roc_auc_score(
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_ranking.py", line 638, in _multiclass_roc_auc_score
    if not np.allclose(1, y_score.sum(axis=1)):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 48, in _sum
    return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial, where)
numpy.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

The error is showing in this respective line

```py
print('(Test set) AUC Score:', roc_auc_score(y_test, clf.predict(X_test), average = 'macro', multi_class = 'ovo'))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Ram Prakash\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_17052\3143009577.py", line 6, in <cell line: 5>
    print('(Test set) AUC Score:', roc_auc_score(y_test, clf_default.decision_function(X_test), average = 'macro', multi_class = 'ovo'))
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_ranking.py", line 566, in roc_auc_score
    return _multiclass_roc_auc_score(
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_ranking.py", line 639, in _multiclass_roc_auc_score
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Target scores need to be probabilities for multiclass roc_auc, i.e. they should sum up to 1.0 over classes
```

I no longer see the above errors. However, the scoring fails and gives me AUC score as `nan`:

```
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py:794: UserWarning: Scoring failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_scorer.py", line 115, in __call__
    score = scorer._score(cached_call, estimator, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_scorer.py", line 367, in _score
    raise ValueError("{0} format is not supported".format(y_type))
ValueError: multiclass format is not supported
```

[image: input]

[image: output]

> Output: `(Cross Validation) AUC Score: nan`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Ram Prakash\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_30780\4160018733.py", line 6, in <cell line: 5>
    print('(Test set) AUC Score:', roc_auc_score(y_test, clf_default.predict_proba(x_test), average = 'macro', multi_class = 'ovo'))
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_ranking.py", line 566, in roc_auc_score
    return _multiclass_roc_auc_score(
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_ranking.py", line 683, in _multiclass_roc_auc_score
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Number of classes in y_true not equal to the number of columns in 'y_score'
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Hi, @AaronKeesing

Comment: "axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1" is the error that I am getting

Comment: This error is in the following line : **bold** `print('(Test set) AUC Score:', roc_auc_score(y_test, clf.predict(X_test), average = 'macro', multi_class = 'ovo'))` @AaronKeesing

Comment: Print the full stacktrace.

Comment: No. Put the error, stacktrace, details about training data, etc. in your question so it's clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`roc_auc_score()` should take the class probabilities in the multiclass case (see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score)). You will need to train SVC with `probability=True`:

```py
clf_default = SVC(kernel='rbf', probability=True)
```

Then use [`predict_proba()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.decision_function) for predictions:

```py
print('(Test set) AUC Score:', roc_auc_score(y_test, clf.predict_proba(X_test), average = 'macro', multi_class = 'ovo'))
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the above code. While running the code I get an error `Target scores need to be probabilities for multiclass 
 roc_auc, i.e. they should sum up to 1.0 over classes` Traceback is added above.

Comment: @Akshita I have edited my answer to clarify for the multiclass case.

Comment: Hi, @Aaron Keesing. Thank you so much. I no longer see the above error message. However, the AUC score is now nan.

Comment: What is the test data like, and what are the predictions like? I think AUC can be undefined if there are no positive examples or no negative examples for a class.

Comment: Hi, @Aaron Keesing There are about 10 features and 8 target values. I have attached a picture above. I am trying to predict the labels for the respective test set.

Comment: Also, now I see this error as well  `ValueError: Number of classes in y_true not equal to the number of columns in 'y_score' `

Comment: So you need to make sure that test data has all classes present.